# Why are E2PDF custom HTML fields not printing from Formidable Forms with Version 1.20.11 and 6.3?

Tags: html, formidable

E2PDF Not printing custom HTML fields from Formidable Forms

I am using Formidable forms with E2PDF. In my formidable form custom HTML fields I have added inputs to be filed in on the client side. The fields are found when "mapped" in E2PDF; however once "printed" or "Downloaded" the fields are blank and the area the field should take up is missing. I have found this article, but am not sure if this is the issue as I do not see the  "DISALLOW_UNFILTERED_HTML" constant or "unfiltered_html" permission in my E2PDF settings.

Any help/guidance is appreciated.

E2PDF: Version 1.20.11
Formidable Forms: Version 6.3

[E2pdf mapped fields] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/801W9.jpg)
[download after form submitted] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/efkso.jpg)]

I found an article on custom HTML but I am looking to see if anyone has confirmation about that being an issue or if I am missing something else.